# How do I use outputCapture correctly for lua debugging on visual studio code (on linux)

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

Currently visual studio code is suffering from a bug (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148887) that is stopping the lua (or any other language) debugger from working, the error looks like this.

```
cd "/home/NAME/Documents/Card Game" ; /home/NAME/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/actboy168.lua-debug-1.55.1-linux-x64/runtime/linux-x64/lua54/lua -e "dofile\[\[/home/NAME/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/actboy168.lua-debug-1.55.1-linux-x64/script/launch.lua\]\];DBG{582}" "/home/NAME/Documents/Card Game/main.lua" 
    /home/NAME/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/actboy168.lua-debug-1.55.1-linux-x64/runtime/linux-x64/lua54/lua: (command line):1: syntax error near '\'
```

I got told I should use "outputCapture" in my launch.json file but I im not a pro at using visual studio, so I dont know what to give outputCature to make it output the errors or run the debugger correctly!

This is my attempt at rerouting the output to the debug console, but nothing happens

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lua",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug lua",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.lua",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "outputCapture": ["stdout"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging says the value must be `"outputCapture": "std"`

Comment: I tried that as well and same result nothing gets output to the debug console or any other console.